# how to have protractor understand angular's resolve state?

Tags: timeout, resolve, angularjs-e2e, protractor

I am writing protractor e2e tests, and I find it annoying that I'm constantly using

```
ptor.sleep(4000)
```

all the time, sometimes it even wait longer, i know sometimes

```
ptor.wait(function(){return true/false; })
```

is a good solution, but how often does wait check the callback function?

is there a more elegant approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ptor.wait` polls every 100 ms. (This is the Webdriver default).

A more elegant approach would depend on your application. Protractor tries to automatically wait for events it knows about ($http, $timeout, angular digests). What is your application doing that makes this an invalid approach? Is there some way that your application could notify the tests when it's done? You could write a custom `waitForMyApp` which would wait until that condition is true - for example, the way Protractor does this behind the scenes is to do a `executeAsyncScript` call, which blocks until the browser returns.